# LEFT INNER JOIN with an OR Operator - Alternatives?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to execute (in Snowflake) a LEFT INNER JOIN with an OR operator in the ON clause but the query is taking too long to run. My question is, is there an alternative in my specific case or any other options to make the query execute quicker? Query below:

```
SELECT T1.EMAIL,
       M.STATUS,
       M.CAMPAIGN_ID,
       M.CAMPAIGN_TYPE
FROM (SELECT VISITOR_ID,
             ACCOUNT_ID,
             CONTACT_ID,
             ROW_KEY,
             LEAD_ID,
             EMAIL,
             CAMPAIGN_UNIQUE_ID
      FROM NORMAL_TOUCHPOINTS NTP
      UNION ALL
      SELECT VISITOR_ID,
             ACCOUNT_ID,
             CONTACT_ID,
             ROW_KEY,
             NULL AS LEAD_ID,
             EMAIL,
             CAMPAIGN_ID
      FROM OPP_TOUCHPOINTS OTP) T1
         JOIN LIST_FACTS LF ON (LF.TP_KEY = T1.ROW_KEY) OR (LF.ATP_KEY = T1.ROW_KEY)
         LEFT JOIN ACCOUNTS A ON A.ID = T1.ACCOUNT_ID
         LEFT JOIN LEADS L ON L.ID = LF.LEAD_ID
         LEFT JOIN MEMBERS M ON ((M.LEAD_ID = T1.LEAD_ID) OR (M.CONTACT_ID = T1.CONTACT_ID)) AND
                                (M.CAMPAIGN_ID = T1.CAMPAIGN_ID)
```

And the LEFT JOIN statement in question is:

```
 LEFT JOIN MEMBERS M ON ((M.LEAD_ID = T1.LEAD_ID) OR (M.CONTACT_ID = T1.CONTACT_ID)) AND
                                    (M.CAMPAIGN_ID = T1.CAMPAIGN_ID)
```

Essentially the LEFT JOIN above is joining based on a matching M.LEAD_ID to the T1.LEAD_ID--and if those are NULL, then it will join on M.CONTACT_ID. Any ideas on how to speed things up?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to boost an OR is to UNION ALL known seperate sets of results..

AND given T1 is aleady an UNION ALL and half already have a known to be NULL for LEAD_ID, why not push the M join earlier.. onto those two UNIONS.

Which means you just need to decide how to split NORMAL_TOUCHPOINTS.. now if when lead_id is not null contact_id will never match that might be a path to have three unions.. But this requires deep your data knowledge.